# Executing Terminal Command from Python (cURL)

Tags: python, macos, curl

I know this has been asked before, but I'm not finding the answer I'm looking for.  Here's what I'm trying to do.. and before you respond, *full disclosure*: this is my first python script.

**Big picture:** 
Concatenate 2 text strings with clipboard text, and run this concatenated string as a command in Terminal in OSX.

Down the line, I'd like the pick apart the results of the command into a file, but first things first.

My current script has no problems concatenating the strings, and copying the concatenation to the clipboard.  I'm not successful in having the terminal execute this command.  Here's what I've got:

---

```
import pyperclip
import os

reqPayload= pyperclip.paste()

fullstring=('curl -HreqPayload:')+reqPayload+(' http://howdy.com/decrypt') 

print(fullstring)

pyperclip.copy(fullstring)

os.system(fullstring)
```

---

ps.  There might be a much smarter way of doing a curl command, so please advise if I should rethink my approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the python requests library

```
import requests
x = requests.post('http://something', json={})
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/